# How to read this custom file in spark-scala using dataframes

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, spark-streaming

I have a file which is of format:

```
ID|Value
1|name:abc;org:tec;salary:5000
2|org:Ja;Designation:Lead
```

How do I read this with Dataframes?
The required output is:

```
1,name,abc
1,org,tec
2,org,Ja
2,designation,Lead
```

Please help

Answer (score 0):

You will need a bit of ad-hoc string parsing because I don't think there is a built in parser doing exactly what you want. I hope you are confident in your format and in the fact that special characters (`|`, `:`, and `;`) do not appear in your fields because it would screw everything up.

That being given, you get your result with a couple of simple `split`s and an `explode` to put each property in the dictionary on different lines.

```
val raw_df = sc.parallelize(List("1|name:abc;org:tec;salary:5000", "2|org:Ja;Designation:Lead"))
   .map(_.split("\\|") )
   .map(a => (a(0),a(1))).toDF("ID", "value")

raw_df 
   .select($"ID", explode(split($"value", ";")).as("key_value"))
   .select($"ID", split($"key_value", ":").as("key_value"))
   .select($"ID", $"key_value"(0).as("property"), $"key_value"(1).as("value"))
   .show
```

result:

```
+---+-----------+-----+
| ID|   property|value|
+---+-----------+-----+
|  1|       name|  abc|
|  1|        org|  tec|
|  1|     salary| 5000|
|  2|        org|   Ja|
|  2|Designation| Lead|
+---+-----------+-----+
```

Edit: alternatively, you can use the `from_json` function (https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.functions$) on the value field to parse it. You would however still need to explode the result into separate lines and dispatch each element of the resulting object in the desired column. With the simple example you gave, this would not be simpler and hence boils down to a question of taste.